# robots.txt - Prevent crawling of mobile site and what write in the meta tag?

Tags: mobile, meta-tags, robots.txt

i want to write a mobile site and i prevent crawling of it. I will disallow everything for yahoo, google, etc.

And what i must write in the meta tag?

Is this code enough or is there more?

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">
```

Answer (score 0):

No that is incorrect. The code below is what you need:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"
```

or if you still want links to be followed on the page use:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
```

Add that in the head section of every page you would like to block from being indexed